# Rails forms do not submit when I load them from a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a strange problem with my rails app. I have several forms not working when I try to submit them coming from a direct link. For example, if I click on "log in" from the home page, it does not work. But if I refresh the page, then I can submit the form. Any idea what's the problem?

Log in view new.html.erb:

```
<div class="main-container form">
  <h2>Log in</h2>

  <div class="form-fields">

  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>

    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>

    <div class="footer-form">
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: 'cta' %>
      </div>
      <div class="links-form">
        <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

</div>
```

User model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :review

  before_create :add_random_id
  private
  def add_random_id
    self.random_id = SecureRandom.uuid unless self.random_id
  end

end
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'registrations'}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I see a small error in your user.rb file. You have
```has_many: review```
when it should be
```has_many :reviews```
but I don't think that is your problem. What does the console show when you click the link after coming from the direct link?

Comment: There is no error so the console does not show up

Comment: You're in the development environment correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to rails, can I change the config to have a console?

Comment: In the terminal, where you run rails server, you can see what happens while you run your app in development mode. What does it print when click the submit button after the coming from the direct link?

Comment: Oh sorry! Well, it does not print anything...

Comment: If the link doesn't fire any request to the server, check your JS assets, maybe you accidentally attach some 'onclick' to it, and then preventDefault..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the following line in my application.js file and it works:

```
//= require turbolinks
```